# Application ROM Manager is uninstalled, but market wants to update it every day

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation, rom-manager

I uninstalled ROM Manager. Since I did so, I've received daily notifications from the Market saying there's an update.

I've logged into the market via the desktop browser and ROM manager is not listed as an installed application. (Though many I have uninstalled ages ago are listed, but that's another matter).

The notifications are annoying. How can I kill ROM Manager once and for all?

HTC Desire running Cyanogenmod7

Comment: How did you uninstall it? AFAIK it's a system app in CM7, so if you used the Market or your phone's Settings it only uninstalled the updates.

Comment: I'm echoing what @eldareathis said, I'm pretty sure ROM Manager is a System app and you only uninstalled the updates to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ROM Manager shouldn't be a required Systems app to run CyanogenMod.  Take a look at the steps over here to remove a system app from your phone: http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Barebones

Something like:

```
adb remount 
adb shell rm -f /system/app/RomManager.apk
```

Comment: ROM Manager is a system app on CM6 as well. It's not required (Replicant removes it).

Comment: I'm not sure why one would want to remove ROM Manager since it alerts you of OS (CM) updates and lets you backup your current ROM, but to each their own.

Comment: @BryanDenny: It's kind of useless if you don't use ClockworkMod recovery, IMHO (I use TeamWin's recovery, for example). Don't you also need the pro/premium version to get CM push updates? I thought that was how it worked at one point, but that could have changed.

Comment: @eldarerathis oh, you may be right. I have the premium version, so I forgot about that

Comment: ROM manager is also not Free Software, which is why Replicant removes it. The point is there are reasons.

Comment: Why? "HTC Desire". I constantly have no more space on the phone. I need to remove all but the essentials.